# Why is node.js giving " Invalid Debug Argument Error" during debugging?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

When I try to debug node.js via VS Code or Chrome, I get an error code 12 (Invalid Debug Argument Error) and cannot debug my code beyond this point.  If I run without debugging, there are no issues but I cannot step through the code using a debugger.

This is part of the messages.  I am already attached to 9229 successfully, but it looks like a child process is trying to do the same.

Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use

Any thoughts?

Comment: have you any news on this?